# Why does passing a Queue cause this function to fail when called with Pool.apply_async?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When I pass a Queue object to a function called using Pool.apply_async, the function fails, as indicated by `ApplyResult.successful()` and the absence of print output. The body of the function does not appear to run at all in this case.

I had planned to use the Queue to synchronize collection of results from separate processes as [suggested by the multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues), but the Queue causes failure even if it is not actually used in the function.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
import time
from random import randint

def sample_function(name, results):
    delay_ms = randint(1, 10)
    print ("{} starting with delay {:d}".format(name, int(delay_ms)))
    time.sleep(delay_ms)
    # results argument is unused! 
    #results.put("{} result".format(name))
    print ("{} ending".format(name))

resultsQueue = Queue()
jobs = ['one','two','three','four', 'five', 'six']

pool = Pool(processes=4)
# fails
jobStatuses = [pool.apply_async(sample_function, args=(job, resultsQueue)) for job in jobs]
# succeeds
#jobStatuses = [pool.apply_async(sample_function, args=(job,'works with string argument')) for job in jobs]

pool.close()
print('closing: no more tasks')
pool.join()

for status in jobStatuses:
    print (status.ready(), status.successful())

while not resultsQueue.empty():
    print(resultsQueue.get())
print('All finished')
```

I can call the same function without `Pool.apply_async` and it will succeed: `sample_function('test without pool', resultsQueue)`. I can also call the `Pool.apply_async` function with a string, and it will succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `RuntimeError` occuring in each `apply_async` call with a `multiprocessing.Queue` which gets silenced.
Changing your code a little bit I was able to trace it:

```
for status in job_statuses:
    print(status.__dict__)
```

outputs:

> {'_value': RuntimeError('Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance',), '_success': False, '_callback': None, '_cache': {}, '_job': 0, '_error_callback': None, '_event': }

x6 times.

Using a `Manager().Queue()` which can be shared among processes solves this.